# Unity 2d collision detection not registering

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript, collision

I am making a game in Unity 3d using the new 2D features found in Unity 4.3. I type the `function OnCollisionEnter` but nothing logs to debug when they collide. Is there something I am missing or should I go about this in a different way. Both objects have a ridgibody and are both continuous collision detection.

```
function OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D) {
    Debug.Log("collision");
}
```

Comment: Do you have colliders on the objects?

Comment: one has a box collider

Comment: now they both have colliders and still doesn't register

Comment: They should have 2D colliders, can you confirm? 2D colliders and not simple colliders. Also, do they have is trigger activated? If you want to use trigger, you should use on trigger enter 2D instead of collision.

Comment: yes they both have 2d box colliders with trigger checked still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the collision table from Unity:

[image: Unity Collision Table]

And here is the documentation page that that comes from, which has all the definitions for the above table and some additional hints: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider.html

Comment: so you dont think it is a problem with my scripts

Comment: I think you are not setting up the colliders/rigid bodies/etc of your game objects. Also, triggers fire OnTriggerEnter, not OnCollisionEnter. The latter, I believe, is fired by non-trigger rigid bodies. Setting something as trigger might not be always desirable. I would say, make sure that how you have setup your game objects will indeed produce what you expect by reading the page and looking at the table.